# Strange case with php mail function and addition parameter “-f”

Tags: php, email

I using php and CodeIgniter to send email but after change the server have following strange problem. 
Each mail are sent to recipient and to sender.
After long debug of this problem I came to the following case.

```
mail("example@exmaple.com",$title,$body,$headers);
```

Work as expect send email only to "example@exmaple.com".

But

```
mail("example@exmaple.com",$title,$body,$headers, "-f example@domain.com ");
```

Send email and on both mail "example@exmaple.com" and  "example@domain.com"

The problem is I do not know why she sends both emails. 
I want to send only to "example@exmaple.com"

Here's what it says about this parameter php.net

The additional_parameters parameter can be used to pass additional flags as command line options to the program configured to be used when sending mail, as defined by the sendmail_path configuration setting. For example, this can be used to set the envelope sender address when using sendmail with the -f sendmail option.

Obviously this parameter needs me but it is only for authentication and should not be sent to the e-mail "example@domain.com",

Comment: if you want to send mail to multiple recipient , use array of send mail address like `send_to =  array(FIRST_EMAIL_ADD,SECOND_EMAIL_ADD);` and use array in mail function.

Comment: So what do you want to ask?

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I was not clear enough.
I edited my question.